# Why my flutter application is not running on avd?

Tags: dart, android-gradle-plugin, flutter-dependencies

[debug console snip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmmop.png)/
[problem section screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gG9Tm.png)
The supplied phased action failed with an exception.
The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.5.20 and higher.
The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version:
root project 'android' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.4.32
Can't use Java 18.0.2.1 and Gradle 7.5 to import Gradle project android.
**I am getting these errors on the problems tab of vs code terminal. Please help me to fix these.**

> > Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.5.20 and higher. The following dependencies do
>   not satisfy the required version: root project 'android' ->
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.4.32
> - Try:
>
> > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> > Run with --scan to get full insights.
>
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 5s Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with
> exit code 1 Exited (sigterm)
> Blockquote

app's build.gradle:

```
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    namespace "com.example.hoolla"
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.hoolla"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

android's build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

pubspec.yaml file:

```
name: hoolla
description: A new Flutter project.
# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `flutter pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number is used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
# In Windows, build-name is used as the major, minor, and patch parts
# of the product and file versions while build-number is used as the build suffix.
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.17.0 <3.0.0'

# Dependencies specify other packages that your package needs in order to work.
# To automatically upgrade your package dependencies to the latest versions
# consider running `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`. Alternatively,
# dependencies can be manually updated by changing the version numbers below to
# the latest version available on pub.dev. To see which dependencies have newer
# versions available, run `flutter pub outdated`.
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  audioplayers: ^0.20.1
  file_picker: ^4.5.1


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  # The "flutter_lints" package below contains a set of recommended lints to
  # encourage good coding practices. The lint set provided by the package is
  # activated in the `analysis_options.yaml` file located at the root of your
  # package. See that file for information about deactivating specific lint
  # rules and activating additional ones.
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter packages.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/audio/


  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

The main.dart file I copied from here:(https://www.fluttercampus.com/guide/220/audio-player-example-flutter/)

I tried many different things: like restarting the app fully, am also a beginner so I tried many online portals where I found the compatibility matrix of gradle, but could not make the head or tail out of it. I have installed java but not familiar with it. **My java version is 18.0.2.1**

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  It isn't sufficient to just post your code.  Please include the errors in your post as text.

Comment: I added the snip

Comment: As I stated, include your errors as text not as an image.  That said, have you read the error?  What version of Kotlin do you have installed?

Comment: C:\Users\HP>kotlin -version
Kotlin version 1.9.0-release-358 (JRE 18.0.2.1+1-1)

Comment: should I post my main.dart file also?

Comment: Why is your ```ext.kotlin_version```  = ```'1.4.32'```?

Comment: I changed it because I thought downgrading the kotlin version will support the dependencies as the error stated

Comment: I also did not download from the site..so I don't know what packages they are using..I just copied their code and pasted it on my main.dart file

Comment: I was right..in their build.gradle file the ext.kotlin version is used 1.4.32...so basically you have to downgrade the kotlin version to match with the dependencies

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the Kotlin Gradle plugin version. In your `build.gradle` file change the `ext.kotlin_version` to `1.8.10`:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

Clean and rebuild the project and it should fix the problem.

Comment: Not working ..the same error is coming

Comment: In fact another error pops up..this time inside the app folders build.gradle file..it says..
unable to resolve class GradleException
 @ line 11, column 15.

Comment: by any means it has to do with my vs code extensions?

Comment: you can check my app folder's build.gradle file at the top description of problem statement.

Comment: Can you please send what error you see after updating the kotlin version to 1.8.10?

Comment: and don't forget to run the `flutter clean` command before you build and run the app

Comment: also try to update the android gradle plugin version `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2'`

Comment: after writing flutter clean now the errors increased

Comment: I was right..in their build.gradle file the ext.kotlin version is used 1.4.32...so basically you have to downgrade the kotlin version to match with the dependencies

Comment: But the new errors are coming as posted in my answer.. please tell me how to resolve those